# Find $ \int \left(\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} dx $ with $f(x)= \frac{x+2}{2x+3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Find $$ \int \left(\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} dx $$ with $f(x)= \frac{x+2}{2x+3}$

I could'nt go ahead after putting $f(x)$ in the integral..I tried substituting $x$ to $t^2$.It didnt work out.

Any hint for what is should do here?

Comment: The integrand is well-defined on $(-\infty,-2)$, $(-3/2,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$. Do you want the primitive function on any particular of these intervals? The general expression will look a bit messy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** : Substitute $u=\sqrt{\frac{2x+4}{2x+3}}$